# Dynamic "SELECT TOP :parameter" in Teradata Macro

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to alter a macro the way that a parameter can be passed to control the max size of the result set.

My idea was this SQL:

```
REPLACE MACRO myMacro
( maxRows INTEGER DEFAULT 100 )
AS
(
    SELECT TOP :maxRows
    FROM myTable;
);
```

But all I get is the message:

> [SQLState 42000] Syntax error,Expected something like an Integer or decimal number between 'top' and ':'.

**It's not possible for me to do this in any other way than a macro.**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
REPLACE MACRO myMacro
( maxRows INTEGER DEFAULT 100 )
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myColumn) AS RowNo, 
        myColumn
    FROM myTable
    WHERE RowNo <= :maxRows;
);
```

Comment: Another option is dynamic SQL in a stored procedure using the DBC.SysExecSQL() function. However, the use of ROW_NUMBER() in this case does affect the results returned. In your original query you did not specify an ordered set.

Comment: I believe `<` should be `<=`.